# How to set the indexPath.row as a variable outside tableview functions to be used in the NSTimer selector function

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview, nstimer

OR How to run a NSTimer selector function inside a tableview funciton on a TableViewController file? I'm still new to this, so please bear with me.

I'm trying to animate an image on a TableViewController using a NSTimer to continuously change the image every half second.

In my understanding, the timer requires a selector, which is a function that sets the counter variable into the cells image.

But I can't seem to get the indexPath.row outside the tableView functions nor can I run the NSTimer function due to the selector.

Here's the code that I have:

```
import UIKit

class tableViewController: UITableViewController {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  ....
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var myCell:cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as cell

    var partySprites = array[indexPath.row]["partySprite"] as? String

    // The fixed 1 should be the dynamic variable as seen in the result function
    let image = UIImage(named: "sprites/\(partySprites!)1.png")
    myCell.partySprite.image = image

//        var timer = NSTimer()
//        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("result"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        return myCell
    }

}
```

And this is what I'd like to do in the result function:

```
        func result() {
            counter++
            if counter == 3 {
                counter = 1
            }

            let image = UIImage(named: "sprites/\(partySprites!)\(counter).png")
            myCell.partySprite.image = image

        }
```

But cannot as the indexPath.row does not exist outside the tableView function nor can this function can be called inside the tableView function.

Thanks!

EDIT: I also have the following class which helps identify the image from the table view cell is also used in the tableViewController when declaring myCell

```
class cell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var partySprite: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to create a custom class for UITableViewCell to handle this... it will be easiler and the code will be cleaner

Comment: @SiuChungChan I'm using a separate class to retrieve the UIImageView and set it in the table view controller; is that the sort of the class you were referring to? Also have just added that sect of code as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement tableview's delegate and datasource, They required three method you have to configure.

You can reference my code. I've test my project, It can work

Note: you have to set a tableviewcell's identifier to "myIdentifier", the one I set in my code. If you don't know where to set, go to `attribute inspector`(right top of your project), Identify property.  and I have many pictures, their name are from "ad1.png" to "ad100.png", You have to change your images' name too.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var aTimer:NSTimer?
    var increcementCount:Int = 1
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        //init a NSTimer
        aTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "increase", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    //this method was called every 0.5 second
    func increase() {
        increcementCount += 1
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    //tableview datasource
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, sectionForSectionIndexTitle title: String, atIndex index: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    //tableview delegate
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "myIdentifier"
        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "ok"
        //set your image
        cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "%@%d.png", "ad", increcementCount))
        return cell
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the following segment mean? - 

`UIImage(named: String(format: "` **%@%d.png** `", "` **ad** `", increcementCount))`

And I'm assuming it reloads the data every 1/2 second? If so, does it affect the memory usage? Thanks!

Comment: @Javz it means build a UIImage with file name, and the file name is "ad1" to "ad100", because every time reload data,  increment add 1.

Comment: thanks! And as to the following questions? Does it affect the memory since it is being constantly reloaded? Thanks again!

Comment: No, it won't. Because it keeps reusing the cell.